# Python, Pandas: Boolean Indexing Comparing DateTimeIndex to Period

Tags: python, pandas

Let's consider a DataFrame that contains 1 row of 2 values per each day of the month of Jan 2010:

```
date_range = pd.date_range(dt(2010,1,1), dt(2010,1,31), freq='1D')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.rand(len(date_range),2), index = date_range)
```

I would like to use the Period `Period('2009-12-28/2010-01-03', 'W-SUN')` to create a boolean indexer that would return a DataFrame containing only from that Period. How can I create such a boolean indexer? - Ideally without resorting to converting the period to a datetime range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the query `pd.Period` object be:

```
query = pd.Period('2009-12-28/2010-01-03', 'W-SUN')
```

You can do this directly in the following ways by accessing it's `start_time` and `end_time` attributes:

1) Using [`DF.truncate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.truncate.html):

```
df.truncate(query.start_time, query.end_time)
```

2) Using Boolean Indexer:

```
df[(df.index >= query.start_time) & (df.index <= query.end_time)]
```

3) Using DateTime Indexing which by default includes both the endpoints:

```
df[query.start_time:query.end_time]
```

All these produce

[image]

Comment: docs on Period  are a little light / PRs to update always welcome